# How to use a function in a stored procedure sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table

```
UserTime
(
    UserTimeId(pk)
    ,DAY
    ,Date
    ,CheckIn
    ,CheckOut
    ,HOURS
)
```

On run time when I click `CheckIn` button, it inserts current time

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertCheckIn]
   @UserID INT,
   @Day varchar(50),
   @Date nvarchar(50),
   @CheckIn nvarchar (50)
as
begin
    insert into UserTime (Userid, [Day], Date, CheckIn)
    values (@UserID, @Day, @Date, @CheckIn)
end
```

and on checkout, I insert the current time.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[UpdateCheckOut]
   @UserID INT,
   @Day varchar(50),
   @Date nvarchar(50),
   @CheckOut nvarchar (50)
as
begin
    update UserTime
    set UserId   = @UserID
       ,[Day]    = @Day
       ,[Date]   = @Date
       ,CheckOut = @CheckOut
    from UserTime
    where UserId = @UserId
end
```

I have a function

```
 DATEADD(SECOND, - DATEDIFF(SECOND, @CheckOut, @CheckIn), @HoursWorked)
```

that take a difference of the time values stored.

I want to store this difference in column `Hours`.

When I insert CheckIn -> store current time. 
On CheckOut, I want to store that time as well as the difference in `Hours`.

How can I implement this?

Comment: add some sample data.

Comment: Sorry to say bu your data types are a mess, you cannot use `DATEDIFF()` function  on a `nvarchar (50)` value. You need to use the appropriate datatypes. for example use DATE datatype for your Date column and do not use sql server key words for your column names. You have used UserID column in your procedure where as it doesnt seem to exist in your table schema.

Comment: @Serpiton I am new to this. Can you give an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestion and tips , Your table design needs some serious attention, I suggest you should have only three columns holding all the information that you are trying to store in multiple different fields with wrong datatypes.

```
CREATE TABLE UserTime
(
UserTimeId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,CheckIn   DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
,CheckOut  DATETIME
)
GO
```

Now have the following stored procedure to insert an entry the checkin time will get the current datetime by default.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertCheckIn]
@UserTimeId INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into UserTime (UserTimeId)
    values (@UserTimeId)

END
```

Now when the person leave the following stored procedure can check out only taking UserID and DATETIME for checkout.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[UpdateCheckOut]
@UserTimeId INT,
@CheckOut   DATETIME = NULL    --<-- If no value is provided it will 
AS                                 -- set it to current datetime here is set
BEGIN                              -- to default NULL
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF (@CheckOut IS NULL)
      BEGIN
         SET @CheckOut = GETDATE();    -
      END 

    UPDATE UserTime
    SET CheckOut     = @CheckOut
    WHERE UserTimeId = @UserTimeId
END
```

**Note**

The other computed value you are trying to store in a column, you should avoid and write a query which gets that value at runtime when required.

Comment: I updated the tables and store procedures. Now how to make use of this function?  DATEADD(SECOND, - DATEDIFF(SECOND, @CheckOut, @CheckIn), @HoursWorked)